# Multi-Level Group By with counts at each level in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I have flat file with data. Some of the main attributes are [Country,State,City,FirstName,LastName,Age,Income,CreditScore,...]

I need following groupping order: Country --> State --> City --> Age

In addition, lets say i need counts at each group level... something can be done easily at RDBMS using GROUP BY! but i do not have database (or simply can't use it), it is flat file data.

One way to do is using HashMap, but at one level or two works great, as levels increase code is complicated...

```
Map<String, Integer> count = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
Iterator<RandomObject> i = r.iterator();

while (i.hasNext()) {
    String key=i.next().getName();
    if (count.containsKey(key)) {
        int rr =Integer.valueOf(count.get(key));
        rr++;
        count.put(key, rr);
    }else{
        count.put(key, 1);
    }

}
```

Is there any clean solution in java for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for clean solution. The best way to do this is using Java 8

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
class Student {

    String stud_id;
    String stud_name;
    String stud_location;

    public String getStud_id() {
        return stud_id;
    }

    public String getStud_name() {
        return stud_name;
    }

    public String getStud_location() {
        return stud_location;
    }



    Student(String sid, String sname, String slocation) {

        this.stud_id = sid;
        this.stud_name = sname;
        this.stud_location = slocation;

    }
}

class Temp
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Stream<Student> studs = 
        Stream.of(new Student("1726", "John", "New York"),
                new Student("4321", "Max", "California"),
                new Student("2234", "Max", "Los Angeles"),
                new Student("7765", "Sam", "California"));
        Map<String, Map<Object, List<Student>>> map= studs.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getStud_name,Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getStud_location)));
                System.out.println(map);//print by name and then location
    }

}
```

{Max={Los Angeles=[Student@214c265e], California=[Student@448139f0]}, John={New York=[Student@7cca494b]}, Sam={California=[Student@7ba4f24f]}}

Comment: how do you do with multi-level?

Comment: Updated for multi-level, by name and location. Hope that helps.